# Error using mex (line 206) Unable to complete successfully

Tags: matlab, linker-errors, mex, lnk2019, lnk2001

I am trying to compile cpp files from [this link](http://people.csail.mit.edu/celiu/OpticalFlow/), but I am receiving the following errors:

```
>> mex OpticalFlow.cpp

LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol mexFunction   
C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_Fe1hah\templib.x :   
fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals    
E:\MATLAB2\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'OpticalFlow.mexw32' failed. 

>> mex GaussianPyramid.cpp

LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol mexFunction  
C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_IWT6TB\templib.x : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals  
E:\MATLAB2\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'GaussianPyramid.mexw32' failed.   
Creating library C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_5guviT\templib.x and object  C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_5guviT\templib.exp  
Coarse2FineTwoFrames.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl OpticalFlow::Coarse2FineFlow(class Image<double> &,class Image<double> &,class Image<double> &,class Image<double> const &,class Image<double> const &,double,double,int,int,int,int)" (?Coarse2FineFlow@OpticalFlow@@SAXAAV?$Image@N@@00ABV2@1NNHHHH@Z) referenced in function _mexFunction  
Coarse2FineTwoFrames.mexw32 : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   
E:\MATLAB2\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'Coarse2FineTwoFrames.mexw32' failed.   
Error using mex (line 206)  
Unable to complete successfully.
```

Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: I am assuming you followed the instructions? From the site: "How to use?
The core of the package is written in C++ and mexed to dll to be called in Matlab. In the /OpticalFlow/mex folder, run the following: mex Coarse2FineTwoFrames.cpp GaussianPyramid.cpp OpticalFlow.cpp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you are trying to compile consists of three cpp files, but they should be compiled into a **single** mex file.
as a result they only have one `mexFunction` symbol defined in them.
Try

```
>> mex -O -largeArrayDims Coarse2FineTwoFrames.cpp GaussianPyramid.cpp OpticalFlow.cpp
```

Comment: Indeed sir, I read the instructions. Now that I compile it into one mex file. I experience this error

c:\users\pc\desktop\opticalflow\mex\Stochastic.h(11) : warning C4067: unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline 

c:\users\pc\desktop\opticalflow\mex\NoiseModel.h(6) : warning C4005: 'PI' : macro redefinition 

c:\users\pc\desktop\opticalflow\mex\Stochastic.h(16) : see previous definition of 'PI'

Comment: Also, warning

warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data

Comment: @Sam: These are warnings, not errors. The mex should be compiled successfully.

Comment: Thank U sir shai,
It works.
You are savior
I get the results.